# Inserted document ID on MongoDB legacy versus edge (PHP)

Tags: php, mongodb

**Legacy:**

```
$doc = array( "firstname" => "Lucille",
              "lastname"  => "Bluth" );
$db->user->Insert( $doc, array( "fsync" => 1 ));
echo (string) $doc['_id'];
```

In MongoDB 4.2.5, the document array doesn't get updated after an insertOne operation to contain the inserted document's ID. What process is recommended to get the ID with edge MongoDB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer Found [HERE](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-insertOne/).

It looks like the recommended method is as follows:

```
$doc = array( "firstname" => "Lucille",
              "lastname"  => "Bluth" );
$result = $db->user->insertOne( $doc );
echo (string) $result->getInsertedId();
```